# Offline OLAP cube file format

Tags: olap

In Excel pivot table you can request the generation of a offline OLAP cube : i.e., a file with the .cub extension. Does anybody know or have any pointer about this file format ?

Thanks, _marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all of the information you need to create them is [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/about-offline-cube-files-HP005247908.aspx), but according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/f03816e6-9ec1-4171-97f4-c62bc1d6b0d1/) post, you can only edit them with SSMS.

EDIT: A C#-only approach is laid out [here](http://netpl.blogspot.com/2008/06/complete-olap-infrastructure-without_27.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use any MS tool for the task; I would need to create the files from scratch.

Comment: See my edit above- you can do it in C# with XMLA.  I think that's as close as you are likely to get, but if C# counts as a 'MS tool' you might be out of luck.

Comment: C# / XMLA would be nice if the actual job to create the cube file was not performed by the ADOMD.NET driver. The XMLA file does not help to understand the actual file format. Thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: Accepted as it seems there's no spec. out there and MS only tools allows for that.

Answer (score 1):

[Here you can find how to transform xmla to .cub](http://blog.stevienova.com/2009/06/25/microsoft-bi-creating-local-olap-cubes-using-xmla-and-ascmd-exe/). If your task is to generate cub files from your application, it can be a good solution. There is much more information on xmla (standard) format than on proprietary .cub. Xmla is a standard and there are opensource implementations - [olap4j](http://www.olap4j.org/), [mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/).

Comment: I have found this website, It looks like a good start. I hope it helps - http://www.cubeslice.com/infocntr.htm.